# Ajax request with Javascript

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a page on which I want to show a couple of MySQL tables.
There is one table on the right that may only change when a different person is selected.
De second table is the main table in the center. I have a dropdown box with contains every person. The results from the selected person is showed in the middle table. There are multiple results for each person so there is a second dropdown box to choose which of these results you want to show. This is al done by a Ajax XMLHTTP request.

The problem is that the right table uses some javascript. I know this is not possible with Ajax in combination with a XMLHTTP-request. But without the javascript I can't make what I want. Is there a way, to show the right table after the javascript is finished doing his work?

I now use frames. This is not very nice. Because I have to style both pages to look nice together, and that's not so easy as said. But this way it is doing as I want it to be.

So I searched the internet (a long time) and just a few minutes before I wanted to give up i found this piece of code (coming from http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxincludes.shtml):

```
function HttpRequest(url){ 
var pageRequest = false //variable to hold ajax object 
   /*@cc_on
      @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
         try {
         pageRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
         }
         catch (e){
            try {
            pageRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }
            catch (e2){
            pageRequest = false
            }
         }
      @end
   @*/

   if (!pageRequest && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined')
      pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()

   if (pageRequest){ //if pageRequest is not false
      pageRequest.open('GET', url, false) //get page synchronously
      pageRequest.send(null)
      embedpage(pageRequest)
   } 
} 

function embedpage(request){ 
   //if viewing page offline or the document was successfully retrieved online (status code=2000)
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || request.status==200)
      document.write(request.responseText)
   }
}

HttpRequest("external.htm") //include "external.htm" onto current page
```

This code works perfectly... The first time. As soon as you change the person the whole page disappears and only the table shows up and firefox keeps "loading" the page (you see that circle going round). I do know how to edit the code above to fit my needs but I have no understanding of Ajax or how to fix this problem. Hopefully someone can help me and give me a good solution! And tell me why the code above isn't working properly?

Thanks in advance!

Milaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It´s been a long time since I´ve seen code like this, but one problem I can see, is that you don´t include any kind of variable in your `XMLHttpRequest`; no user ID or anything. Is it just supposed to load a static page?

And is there any reason you can´t use a library like jQuery? It´s no magic bullet but it will make your life and ajax requests a lot easier.

Comment: Well this was an example I used from internet, I thought my version which includes some variables didn't made any difference.
I know jQuery, but is that better? Is it easier?
I know some basics from it, so I would have to learn everything (including Ajax?).

Comment: @Milaan, I think it would be good to get rid of the frames (with or without jQuery) and you could use the most basic ajax request to put the output of your php scripts directly where you want it using `.load()`: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks jeroen! That is indeed a better way than my frames (I never use them myself but it seemed the only solution).
Should I do the middle table also with jQuery?
It might be better if I did, right?

Comment: @Milaan I would use the same methods for everything, that makes things easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) This definitely helps me al lot! I'll get started on it asap!

Answer (score 2):

`document.write` only works when the page is loading for the first time, Once the page rendering is done, calling `document.write` will clear the page first.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write

What you might want to do instead is:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1 || request.status==200) {
    var elm = document.createElement('div');
    elm.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elm);
}
```

Comment: Wat should i change it into then? 
I tried: <code> document.getElementById('maintable').innerHTML = response Text; </code> 
But that didn't work either...
Or did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use dom functions to add your downloaded content to the existing document, like:

```
document.getElementById('mypanel').innerHTML = '<html code goes here>';
```

The best idea probably would be to use a slim javascript framework lie jquery which helps you with browser compatibility.

Comment: Jeroen said the same thing. So the best thing for me is to see how jQuery works with AJAX-requests. 
So I let jQuery run an Ajax request, which returns the tables and then let the jQuery run an Javascript over the returned table?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery should make things easier for you. Your code should look something like this.

```
$.post("somepage.php", function(data){
   $("#divID").html(data);
});

<div id="divID"></div>
```

And `somepage.php` could be something like this:

```
<?php
   // get table content
   echo "<table>...</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! This is indeed a lot better. I knew jQuery already but not that it could do all this. This is indeed much handier. Thanks!